# Create table from select in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle9i

I would like to do something like this:

```
create table NEW_TABLE (select * from OLD_TABLE where id=3582)
```

And have a new table created from the resulting columns of that select statement.

I bet its possible in mySQL, but how to do it in Oracle?

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS select * from OLD_TABLE where id=3582
```

Comment: I would also add any additional info (storage, logging, etc) as well: create table new_table tablespace MY_TBLSPACE nologging ... as select ...

Comment: Does the select statement have to be within brackets?